# Where does "wasted" propeller power go?

Tags: propeller, wing-tip-vortex

Aircraft propellers are very efficient, with around 80-90% of input horsepower being applied to axial flow. However, that raises the question of where the remaining 10-20% of energy goes. I'm specifically wondering about the percentages that go into specific things, such as:

- Noise (vibration of the air)
- Heat (random vibration of the air)
- Centrifugal flow (impulse applied orthogonal to the propeller axis)

On that last note, I'm curious about how much of centrifugal flow is "blade chasing" (following the movement direction of the blade that created it), and how much is instead span-wise along the blade

I know this is a rather strange sounding question, but any nonrandom motion is at least theoretical able to have some energy extracted. I know this is part of how contra-rotating propellers gain increased aerodynamic efficiency over traditional propeller systems, as the second propeller can utilize some of the centrifugal flow of the first to generate additional thrust. My theory is that, by mounting propellers close to the tip of a wing with top blade moving away from the center line, some of this centrifugal flow could be exploited to "pump" against span-wise flow. But even before the obvious practical concerns, this theory is dependent on there being enough unused energy in the system to run it without additional power load being required

Comment: Heat, as everything that goes wasted. This would be a nice question for physics.se

Comment: Some of it, yes, but I highly doubt a whole 20% of the applied power is generating heat

Comment: Could it be drag?  BTW heat would not apply to brake horsepower, only to engine efficiency delivering that horsepower from fuel burned, right?

Comment: @RileyRosell: why? There are not much options. Sound also go to heat (and I do not think it will consume too much energy, but you can estimate: think dB of an airplane and of an amplifiers, and the Watt of the amplifier). Some *wind" power, but also I do not think too much energy. I doubt it will break some molecules, radiation is possibly just from heat. Maybe some push backward (which requires so additional force, and so we should double count energy), but would it just create heat?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: drag is finally heat too 

Comment: How much power is converted to sound is negligible.  How much power you could then practically extract from that sound is even more negligible!

Comment: I'm not looking to extract energy from sound or heat. My plan is to take energy from the spiraling motion the propeller imparts on the air. That is, a propeller will, in addition to sending air backwards at increased speed, will also impart a tangential velocity in the direction of blade travel: at the part of the disk where the blade moves up, the Propwash should be diverted upwards. It should divert downwards on down movement, etc.

Comment: Btw the claim that "*ContraRotating Propellers gain increased aerodynamic efficiency over traditional propeller systems*" isn't correct. Two close contra-rotating propellers lose some 10 to 15% power due to aerodynamic inefficiency in respect to two isolated propellers (plus the mechanical complications).

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, it all ends up as heat.  It always does.

Initially, there is some that is held in the swirl velocity of the propeller slipstream.  Over time, this velocity difference dissipates due to the friction within the air -- which generates heat.

There have been many studies on wingtip propulsors as a means of either increasing propulsion efficiency or decreasing induced drag.  It has many complicating factors, but it is something that others have studied from time to time.

Comment: Eventually, yes, but my question is more about immediately behind the propeller disk

Comment: @RileyRosell: it goes in aerodynamic drag which eventually get dissipated on heat due viscosity. Some power is also dissipated in the gearbox connecting the propeller to the engine: in this case the dissipation is due local structural deformations which eventually also transform in heat. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @RileyRosell I addressed this -- there is a swirl velocity.  This can be recovered to an extent.  People have studied placing propellers at the wingtip.  There is a measurable benefit to doing so.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't mean to sound snippy